# Pry: alias for whereami command

Tags: ruby, configuration, alias, pry

Is there a shorthand for the `whereami` command in Pry ?

If not, is there a way to define an alias for Pry commands in config like `.pryrc` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Couldn't find any built-in shorthand, but adding this to `~/.pryrc` seems to do the trick:

```
Pry.config.commands.alias_command "@", "whereami"
```

More info on [Prys's Pry rc Wiki page](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Pry-rc)

Comment: Hi, i think we're going to add "@" as an official alias for `whereami` in an upcoming release